# Speed up recursive method by converting into iterative

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, iteration, dynamic-programming

I'm writing a dynamic programming algorithm in `Python` which seems to be working perfectly for smaller inputs but it times out for large inputs probably because of the recursive calls. I read this [article](http://blog.moertel.com/posts/2013-05-11-recursive-to-iterative.html) online which says that most modern programming languages don't deal with recursion well and it's a better idea to convert them into an iterative method.

My algorithm is as follows:

```
def get_val(x,y,g,i,xlast,ylast):
    # checks if array over
    if(i>(len(x)-1)):
        return 0
    # else returns the max of the two values
    # dist returns the euclidian distance between the two points
    # the max condition just decides if it's profitable to move to the 
    # next x and y coordinate or if it would be better to skip this particular (x, y)
    return max(g[i]-dist(x[i],y[i],xlast,ylast) + get_val(x,y,g,i+1,x[i],y[i]),get_val(x,y,g,i+1,xlast,ylast))
```

I have been trying to improve its performance but I'm not really sure about the steps I should take to ensure that it doesn't time out on large inputs.

Comment: can you provide the input and expected output , like a small example

Comment: What does your function *do*?

Comment: I updated the question to add some more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing a **dynamic programming** algorithm implies that you are already dealing with the recursive calls, so your current code is not dynamic programming yet.

You need to identify what is causing the problem and then provide a solution which take less steps to compute your function in exchange of memory consumption, this is, storing function calls results to avoid a new calculation of the same call.

I don't know all the details of your problem but it seems to have an [optimal substructure property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_substructure).

You will find a guide on how to tell what kind of problem you are dealing with and how to solve it [here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLqM7alHXFySGbXhWx7sBJEwY2DnhDjmxm)

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it does have an optimal substructure property. I will check that link and create a substructure for the same, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If i figured out what you arr trying to accomplish, you could use a generator to go to the next step. See these generator tricks:

http://linuxgazette.net/100/pramode.html

Or visit

https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators